# Using YouTube as a CDN

Tags: cms, youtube, cdn

Why isn't YouTube used as a CDN for video and audio files? Through YouTube's api and developer tools, it would be possible to post all media files to YouTube from a CMS and then make a call to them when needed. This seems like it's within YouTube's TOS, it's a cost-effective way to store, retrieve, and distribute media files, and it could also make for easy monetization.

I ask because I'm working on a new project for a public radio station. I can't figure out the real downside to this sort of an implementation.

Comment: If you mean serving video from Youtube, then there are business account for just this purpose. That said, this isn't really a programming question, and is probably better asked on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: You're right, it probably doesn't belong in this forum. Is there a way to move this question to the forum you suggested?

Comment: we are in process of doing that.. :)

Answer (score 1):

We've used this for projects in the past, because YouTube's infrastructure is so open -- not just as a CDN but also as a way to deal with uploads and conversion.

The only real downside we found is the watermark. You can use custom players, so you aren't limited to clunky YouTube players.

Some clients initially object to the watermark, but when you point out  that *everyone* uses YouTube these days, they change their minds.

I'd recommend this to anyone doing video on their site.

Answer (score 0):

There are projects like that. For example [Medioh studio](https://studio.medioh.com/). I'm working on such projects too.